# how to read and pass the variables from xml file to php script

Tags: php, xml, com

How can i read and pass the variables which are coming in through an xml file as an input to a php file ?

Scenario is my COM object pulls data from an application, i need to pass this information to a php script. How can i do this ? Can i use xml to pass this info to a php file which is called by initiating a web browser.

Any inputs will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

php provides you with easy to use basic XML-handling. check:

[simpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Basic logic:

generate your XML

pass xml file path to php

let simplexml do the parsing

hth

k

Answer (score 0):

See this link https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php for all kinds of ways PHP can parse XML. They are:

```
# DOM
# DOM XML (PHP 4)
# libxml
# qtdom
# SDO
# SDO-DAS-Relational
# SDO DAS XML
# SimpleXML
# WDDX
# XML Parser
# XMLReader
# XMLWriter
# XSL
# XSLT (PHP4)
```

SimpleXML is one of the simplest, indeed but it sometimes is to simple and can't handle more advanced manipulation.